# Notifications are removed regularly and energy saving mode activated spontaneously

Tags: samsung, notifications, battery-saver

I have a Samsung Galaxy A51 phone, 2 or 3 years old. Since some time, out of nothing (like just after using the phone for some time, when getting out of screen lock), I see notifications (like WhatsApp, mail, etc.) icons on the main page.

However, before I have the chance to look at them/click them, the phone gets into energy (battery) savings mode spontaneously and all notifications are gone (when disabling energy savings mode manually). So, I have to find in all applications what 'news' there is.

[image]

Is there a solution to get rid of this spontaneous saving mode activations? (without disabling it when I want to do it manually to save battery power) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to **turn off Adaptive Battery Saving** if you go to **Device Care**, tap the **three-dot button**, and then tap **Automation**. So now your phone won't turn on the Battery Saver by itself.

Sample Images Attached

[image: First Image] [image: Second Image]

Comment: Thanks, although the screenshot looked slightly different on my phone, I found similar options which I switched off (since about 4 hours), and didn't get the annoying screen saver problems again.